# Set kerning with GDI+ when drawing text

Tags: .net, image-processing, gdi+

Is it possible to set the kerning when drawing text with GDI+? If not does anyone know of a decent image library that enables this?

Cheers, Ian.

Comment: Wow, I wish I knew the answer to this. I have the exact same issue as I'm attempting to create PowerPoint output and strings at certain sizes need kerning turned on or off.

Answer (score 0):

I found C++ code on CodeGuru which accounts for the Kerning Pairs and draws with GDI+. It's not .NET so interop would be needed or you could put the code into a C++/CLI assembly.

[Make GDI+ Less Finicky About Fonts](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/gdi/fonthandlinganddetection/article.php/c10621/Make-GDI-Less-Finicky-About-Fonts.htm)

Essentially, you need to get the font's Kerning Pairs and assemble the GDI+ drawing path for a given string. I was able to open, build and run his code with Visual Studio 2013 with not much effort and it does the kerning properly. ex. draw "SAVVA" with Garamond will kern the AV pair properly.